# Auto end date by selecting number of weeks or months from start date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I have text filed for number of weeks and i have date-picker to choose start date.

How can i have end date based on my selected number of weeks?

What if i have text field for number of months and getting end date based on selecting start date?

i tried this but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#start_date').bind('change', function() {
   var days = $('#week_number').val() * 7;
  var endDate = new Date($(this).val());
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + days);
  $('#end_week_return').val( (endDate.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' + endDate.getDate() + '/' + endDate.getFullYear() );
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Above code is seems to be fine. The problem will be in some other part of the page,  may be in your header js files, or in html elements. I have created a sample html file please try this and it may help you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( "#start_date" ).datepicker();
$('#start_date').bind('change', function() {
var days = $('#week_number').val() * 7;
var endDate = new Date($(this).val());
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + days);
$('#end_week_return').val( (endDate.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' +    endDate.getDate() + '/' + endDate.getFullYear() );
 });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  No of weeks: <input type="text" id="week_number" />
  Start date: <input type="text" id="start_date" />
  End date:<input type="text" id="end_week_return" />
</body>
```